# Skype autostart with Empathy in Ubuntu

Tags: empathy, skype

I'm using the Empathy and installed the 'pidgin-skype' package to use Skype in Empathy. It's work just perfect, but when I open the Empathy it doesn't start skype automatically.

In settings it's possible to use mark "autostart" and it ask for "Skype Path". I tried with "/usr/bin/skype" (which open skype trough terminal), but it doesn't work.

I tested with Pidgin, and it work without changing any settings. The path is wrong or is any problem with the package?

And if doesn't work, is it possible to automatically open Skype everything Empathy is open with other way? Some script or workaround?

Thanks